Clarification on the use of the Utilize action with spell material components
The Bless spell (PHB'24, p. 247) requires to use a holy symbol as a material component. So does that mean I need to use the Utilize action (PHB'24 p. 377) to reach and hold that material component with my free hand or can I use the Utilize action to sheathe a sword and then reach the holy symbol as an inalienable part of a spell casting action? In PHB'14, the Utilize action was described as Other Activity p. 190. The spell itself doesn't really matter.

Correction: The Utilize Action in 2014 was not in the "Other Activity", which describes the free object interaction that still exists in 2024. The Utilize Action in 2014 is the "Use an Object" action found on page 193.

Casting a spell does not use the Utilise action
Most use them use the Magic action, but some use a Bonus action or Reaction (PHB p.236 Casting Time). There is no suggestion that any other action is needed.
“A spell’s components are the physical requirements [of the spell].” (PHB p.236 Components) so, they are simply part of casting the spell. Just like when you take the Attack action, using your sword is simply part of that.
“The spellcaster must have one hand free to access [material components].” (PHB p.237 Material (M)). No further requirements.
Of course, if you keep your holy symbol stowed at the bottom of your backpack, then the DM may well reuse you to use an action to fish it out; just as if that’s where you chose to keep your sword. But most characters keep the stuff they need handy.

I was a little confused because if you want to make a melee attack you need to be holding a sword already, and if you're not holding a sword you first need to use a free action and draw the sword from its sheath. So I naively assumed that if you're not holding a holy symbol you first need to use a free action and draw it.
